# Cakephp : Show custom error page on LINK not found

Tags: cakephp

My site have implemented custom errors but only when in post not found,

For example : domainname.com/post/IFslugnotexists rediect to cutom error. (Fires only when POST Not found)

But outside of post path it doesnt throw any custom error, just redirect to homepage.

So, i want to implement custom error for link not found even outside of POST path.

i have tried some examples and tutorials from StackOverflow but none of them helped me.

Question is : how to disable this redirect to homepage when link is not found?

And is there any example that will help me to show custom errors on ANY LINK not found?

This is what I have configured now in Config/Core.php

```
 Configure::write('Exception', array(
        'handler' => 'ErrorHandler::handleException',
        'renderer' => 'ExceptionRenderer',
        'log' => true
    ));
```

and in Controllers/AppController.php

```
function _setErrorLayout() {
        if ($this->name == 'CakeError') {
            $this->layout = 'client';
            $this->redirect("/homes/error");
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add your code to question

Comment: @Salines , I just added, Thanks.

Comment: Let me guess, you haven't even tried to look at the document? https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/errors.html#customize-error-templates